# Direct python script through proxy

Tags: python, proxy

I'm using *requests* to make a simple web crawler, how would I go about directing all of the script's functions through a proxy so whatever website I am crawling doesn't know it is me?

Answer (score 0):

To use requests to obtain response behind a proxy in script or to use urllib2 features with proxy use following snippet:

```
proxy_url = "https://proxy:port"
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': proxy_url})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
url1 = "https://api_url"
req1 = urllib2.Request(url1)
print "response from API call is below"
res1 = urllib2.urlopen(req1)
response1 = res1.read()
print response1
jsonobj1 = json.loads(response1)
```